# Is setting parent state on child mount an anti-pattern?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a form with React, and have created a `<Field />` component that needs to render different wrapper elements based on the number of children of a specific type.

For instance, if the field wraps a single input, it should render a wrapper `<div />` and a `<label />`. However if it wraps multiple inputs, it should render a `<fieldset />` and a `<legend />`.

Crucially, the children are not necessarily direct descendants of the `<Field />` component, so counting the `children` with `React.Children.count` won't work.

I can easily accomplish this by setting the parent field state when an child input mounts, for instance:

```
const FormFieldContext = createContext({});

// Simplified Field component
const Field = ({ label, children, ...props }) => {
  const [fieldCount, setFieldCount] = useState(0);
  const Wrapper = fieldCount > 1 ? 'fieldset' : 'div';
  const Label = fieldCount > 1 ? 'legend' : 'label';

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Label>{label}</Label>
      <FormFieldContext.Provider value={{ setFieldCount }}>
        {children}
      </FormFieldContext.Provider>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

// Inside <Checkbox />
const Checkbox = ({ name, ...props }) => {
  const { setFieldCount } = useContext(FormFieldContext);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    setFieldCount(count => count + 1);

    return () => {
      setFieldCount(count => count - 1);
    };
  }, [setFieldCount, name]);

  return ( /** etc */ );
};
```

However my gut tells me this is an anti-pattern, since:

- It causes an immediate re-render.
- Presumably it's impossible to make SSR friendly, since you are relying on a mount-based side-effect. This means the SSR version will not take into account the children.

Is it better to give up on this and force the consumer to manually set a `isFieldset` prop on the `<Field />` component? Or is there a smarter way of accomplishing this?

Desired usage:

```
{# Renders a div and a label #}
<Field name="email" label="Enter your email">
  <TextInput type="email" />
</Field>

{# Renders a legend and a fieldset #}
<Field name="metal" label="Select your metals">
  <Checkbox label="Bronze" value="bronze" />
  <Checkbox label="Silver" value="silver" />
</Field>
```

```html
<div class="form-field">
  <label for="email">Enter your email</label>
  <input type="email" id="email" />
</div>

<fieldset class="form-field">
  <legend>Select your metals</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="metal" value="bronze" /> Bronze
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="metal" value="silver" /> Silver
  </label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: It indeed "feels" a bit like an antipattern and ties the Form and Field components together. I would create a separate component for the Fieldset variant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually possible to recursively get all the children in the React component tree from your `children` props, and when you have all the children you can count how many components of type `CheckBox` etc. to determine how the children should be wrapped.

There are probably more elegant ways, but in the code example below I `.reduce` the immediate children to a flattened array containing *all* children using `getChildrenRecursively`.

```
const getChildrenRecursively = (soFar, parent) => {
    if(typeof parent === "string") return soFar.concat(parent);

    const children = Array.isArray(parent.props.children) ? 
    parent.props.children : 
    React.Children.toArray(parent.props.children);

  const childCount  = children.length;

    if(childCount <= 0) {
    return soFar.concat(parent);
  } else {
    return soFar.concat([parent], children.flatMap(child => getChildrenRecursively([], child)));
  }
}
```

Not 100% sure how well this solution will work with your state logic etc, but I thought you could find it useful.

```js
const getChildrenRecursively = (soFar, parent) => {
 if(typeof parent === "string") return soFar.concat(parent);
  
 const children = Array.isArray(parent.props.children) ? 
   parent.props.children : 
    React.Children.toArray(parent.props.children);
  
  const childCount  = children.length;
  
 if(childCount <= 0) {
   return soFar.concat(parent);
  } else {
   return soFar.concat([parent], children.flatMap(child => getChildrenRecursively([], child)));
  }
}

const MyInput = ({placeholder} ) => <input placeholder={placeholder} ></input>;


const MyComp = ({children}) => {
 const childArr = React.Children.toArray(children);
  // get all children in hierarcy
  const flattenedChildren = childArr.reduce(getChildrenRecursively, []);
  
  const numberOfInputs = flattenedChildren
   .filter(child => child.type && child.type.name === "MyInput").length;
  
  const Wrapper = numberOfInputs > 1 ? 'fieldset' : 'div';

  
 return (
   <div>
       <Wrapper className="form-element">
          <legend>{numberOfInputs} input(s)</legend>
          <div>{children}</div>
        </Wrapper>
    </div>
  )
}


const App = () => {
 return (
      <div>
        <MyComp>
          <MyInput placeholder="Some input #1" />
          <div>
            <span>Some non-input element</span>
          </div>
        </MyComp>
        <MyComp>
          <MyInput placeholder="Some input #1" />
          <div>
            <div>
               <MyInput placeholder="Some nested input #2" />
            </div>
            <div>
              <span>Some non-input element</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </MyComp>
      </div>
   )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

```css
fieldset {
 margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
 border: 1px solid teal;
 padding: 20px;
}

div.form-element {
  border: 1px solid teal;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It didn't occur to me that you could recursively get children - definitely an option.